# How to pass data in Navigator.pushNamed?

Tags: flutter, navigation, bloc

How to pass data from page A(invoiceListScreen) to pageB `BlocProvider`?

**PageA.dart**

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, AppRoute.invoiceListScreen,arguments: id);
```

**app_route.dart**

```
class AppRoute{
  static const invoiceListScreen = '/invoiceListScreen';

    static final _invoiceListScreenRoute = Routes(
      invoiceListScreen,
      BlocProvider(
        create: (_) => sl<InvoiceCubit>(),
        child: PageBScreen(),
      ));

 static Route? onGenerateRoutes(RouteSettings settings) {
   
    if (settings.name == invoiceListScreen ) {
      return _invoiceListScreenRoute.materialRoute;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: See the official docs and example: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments

Comment: @WSBT but what if wrapped by BlocProvider?

Answer (score 1):

You can read the argument passed using `setting.arguments` then you can type cast and use that value to create new block for your new screen.

```
class AppRoute{
  static const invoiceListScreen = '/invoiceListScreen';

 static Route? onGenerateRoutes(RouteSettings settings) {
   
    if (settings.name == invoiceListScreen ) {
      final int id = settings.arguments as int; // considering the argument 'id' as int
      return Routes(
      invoiceListScreen,
      BlocProvider(
        create: (_) => sl<InvoiceCubit>(id),
        child: PageBScreen(),
      )).materialRoute;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I get issue in this line   `create: (_) => sl<InvoiceCubit>(id),`

```_Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.
Try removing the extra positional arguments, or specifying the name for named arguments_```